# load() method error

Tags: jquery

I have the following code whick is not working.
Trying from my localhost to get some string generated via servlet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load("http://www.domain.es/generate.cfg");
});
```

http://www.domain.es/generate.cfg generates a string containing name/value pairs:

color=red&size=big&model=4

I also have a div with id="content" where I want to show that string, so that I can capture afterwards.

However div is not displaying anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you confirm that http://www.domain.es/generate.cfg does actually return what you're expecting it to by putting that url in the main address bar of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see in firebug in case you are getting any javascript error. Also not sure why * added before and after script